# How to prevent CKEditor insertHtml to wrap element within <p> in webkit browsers?

Tags: webkit, ckeditor, smarty, wysiwyg

Im trying to build a front-end page to allow my users to build [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) templates with [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) wysiwyg editor.

Im using the [insertHtml](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertHtml) function to add a button with special attributes (needed to parse it into an smarty variable in the back-end):

```
// initialize ckeditor
$('textarea.editor').ckeditor({
    contentsCss: '/css/test.css'
});
// get ckeditor instance
ckeditorInstance = $('textarea.editor').ckeditorGet();
// Use some elements (outside the textarea) to add buttons/tokens
// to wysiwyg textarea
$("a.tinymce.tinymce-insert-var").click(function(){
    ckeditorInstance.insertHtml(
        '<input type="button" readonly="readonly" var="{$user-&gt;name}" '
        + 'class="placeholder" value="User Name" />'
    );
});
```

This works fine on Firefox, IE8 and opera, but with Chrome/Chromium/Safari the button is inserted between a `<p>` element.

Is there a way to avoid this, or a callback that i can use to remove the paragraph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem as well. This is how I did it...

```
var editor = $('textarea[name=content]').ckeditorGet();
var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<p>I am a new paragraph</p>' );
editor.insertElement( element );
```

Comment: When i insert html via insertHtml or insertElement, the code i inserted does not persist in the editor. If i click the show source code button right after i insert the nem HTML its there, but when i close turn off the source code button the html i inserted is lost. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using jQuery also... why don't you force the inclusion of the p tag within CKEditor's .insertHtml function, then follow it up with jQuery's [.unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to always remove the p tags?

Answer (score 0):

in the main ckeditor config-file there is an option to disable automatic <p> inserts.
try to change the value of CKConfig.EnterMode and CKConfig.ShiftEnterMode for example to 'br'.

Felix

Comment: Tryed, it really stop ckeditor from insert the <p>, but it still insert some &nbsp; that break the html layout (i dont need the br neither!) well, i guess this is the correct answer, even if doesnt solve my problem ;(